# Does Harry ever apologise for something that was his fault?

Tags: harry-potter

For the purpose of writing an English paper, I need to find examples of Harry Potter apologizing and making amends for a problem that he truly was the cause of, but can't find any.

Comment: So your task in class is to go on a wild goose chase in seven relatively long novels to find a specific scenario? Doesn't sound like the coolest assignment…

Comment: @tobiasvl that wasn't the assignment. The assignment is on healthy relationships in pop culture, and a large example to help me use Harry would be if he made amends for something that he was at fault for, which is a healthy thing to do.

Comment: If I had to make a wild shot in the dark, I'd starting looking in Deathly Hallows when he is the cause of Ron and Hermione being dragged around the length and breadth of England. Or when Ron came back in time to destroy the horcrux, there might have been an apology there.

Comment: I'm downvoting this as it shows a lack of research. You're missing the point, #ReadTheBooks :)

Comment: @Mooz - I'm upvoting. Finding the answers isn't trivially simple. #ReadingAMillionWordsisTricky

Comment: @Mooz Read the books? I've read them a billion times. This is simply a case of "I can't think of the answer off the top of my head, and google only gives results for Rowling apologizing for killing characters, so I'm going to ask this community because the paper is due in 3 days". Don't EVER tell me to read the books. I'm a gorram expert at this shit

Comment: @albusseveruspotter **1/2** I understand I may have offended you by saying read the books, and for that I apologise. I'd like to explain that it was said 'in jest', which is why I 'hash-tagged' it. I believe the teacher wants you to 'read the books', which is why I suggested that.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter **2/2** You say you're an expert and have read it `a billion times`, yet you can't think of this off the top of your head? You've either left this too late to have sufficient time to find the answer yourself, or the teacher has given you a task to complete in too short a time (3 days?) and you should ask for an extension. Either way, this shows lack of research to me as you're making us do your leg-work.

Comment: @albusseveruspotter On a side note, I personally don't care, but careful using bad language here, especially for the next little while since the site is under stringent scrutiny at the moment :)

Answer (score 14):

Er yeah, I dunno how much use these'll be for your homework, but for the purposes of the question, he apologises at least twice in *The Order of the Phoenix* for his outbursts and general lack of tact.

The first is after Harry takes out his anger at the fact that people (e.g. Seamus) have been saying that Harry is lying about Voldemort on Hermione:

> 'Yes, Lavender thinks so too,' she said gloomily.
>
> 'Been having a nice little chat with her about whether or not I'm a lying, attention-seeking prat, have you?' Harry said loudly.
>
> 'No,' said Hermione calmly. 'I told her to keep her big fat mouth shut about you, actually. And it would be quite nice if you stopped jumping down our throats, Harry, because in case you haven't noticed, Ron and I are on your side.'
>
> There was a short pause.
>
> 'Sorry,' said Harry in a low voice.
>
> 'That's quite all right,' said Hermione with dignity.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.201 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 12, *Professor Umbridge*

The second is a little more arguable. It's not really his fault, but he apologises for putting his foot in it with Ginny somewhat after overhearing the conversation in St Mungo's that the adults were having about how he could be being possessed. He hides away from everyone, including Ginny.

> 'I didn't want anyone to talk to me,' said Harry, who was feeling more and more nettled.
>
> 'Well, that was a bit stupid of you,' said Ginny angrily, 'seeing as you don't know anyone but me who's been possessed by You-Know-Who, and I can tell you how it feels.'
>
> Harry remained quite still as the impact of these words hit him. Then he turned on the spot to face her.
>
> 'I forgot,' he said.
>
> 'Lucky you,' said Ginny coolly.
>
> 'I'm sorry,' Harry said, and he meant it.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.442 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 23, *Christmas on the Closed Ward*

He also apologises to Dumbledore for his lackadaisical approach to securing the memory from Slughorn. For the purposes of your essay you might do well to read the whole conversation about the topic, beginning "Dumbledore heaved a deep sigh, then said, 'But never mind my staff problems. [...]'", but for the purposes of this answer I shall only quote:

> Silence fell between them again, the most uncomfortable silence Harry had ever experienced with Dumbledore; it seemed to go on and on, punctuated only by the little grunting snores of the portrait of Armando Dippet over Dumbledore's head. Harry felt strangely diminished, as though he had shrunk a little since he had entered the room.
>
> When he could stand it no longer he said, 'Professor Dumbledore, I'm really sorry. I should have done more ... I should have realised you wouldn't have asked me to do it if it wasn't really important.'
>
> 'Thank you for saying that, Harry,' said Dumbledore quietly. 'May I hope, then, that you will give this matter higher priority from now on? There will be little point our meeting after tonight unless we have that memory.
>
> 'I'll do it, sir, I'll get it from him,' Harry said earnestly.
>
> 'Then we shall say no more about it just now,' said Dumbledore more kindly, 'but continue with our story where we left off. You remember where that was?'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - pp.401-2 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 20, *Lord Voldemort's Request*

Another example is mentioned by Valorum [in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159624/does-harry-ever-apologise-for-something-that-was-his-fault#comment420146_159629). In *The Goblet of Fire* Harry apologises to Dumbledore for venturing into his Pensieve (and his memories!) without asking:

> 'I was using the Pensieve when Mr Fudge arrived for our meeting, and put it away rather hastily. Undoubtedly I did not fasten the cabinet door properly. Naturally, it would have attracted your attention.'
>
> 'I'm sorry,' Harry mumbled.
>
> Dumbledore shook his head.
>
> 'Curiosity is not a sin,' he said. 'But we should exercise caution with our curiosity ... yes, indeed ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - pp.519-20 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 30, *The Pensieve*

Comment: He's sorry about using Dumbledore's pensieve; "*‘I was using the Pensieve when Mr Fudge arrived for our meeting, and put it away rather hastily. Undoubtedly I did not fasten the cabinet door properly. Naturally, it would have attracted your attention.’
‘I’m sorry,’ Harry mumbled.
Dumbledore shook his head.
‘Curiosity is not a sin,’ he said. ‘But we should exercise caution with our curiosity … yes, indeed …’*"

Comment: this could actually work!!

Comment: He's sorry for upsetting Ginny by forgetting that she'd been possessed (in Book 5) "*‘Well, that was a bit stupid of you,’ said Ginny angrily, ‘seeing as you don’t know anyone but me who’s been possessed by You-Know-Who, and I can tell you how it feels.’
Harry remained quite still as the impact of these words hit him. Then he turned on the spot to face her.
**‘I forgot,’ he said.**
‘Lucky you,’ said Ginny coolly.
**‘I’m sorry,’ Harry said, and he meant it**. ‘So … so, do you think I’m being possessed, then?’*"

Comment: He apologises in book 6 for making them have to have additional security. Arguably he could just stay away... "*‘Millamant’s Magic Marquees … they’re very good. Bill’s escorting them … you’d better stay inside while they’re here, Harry. I must say it does complicate organising a wedding, having all these security spells around the place.’
‘I’m sorry,’ said Harry humbly.
‘Oh, don’t be silly, dear!’ said Mrs Weasley at once*

Comment: @Valorum I think it's arguable, I mean, he avoided people for a host of reasons, he felt afraid, contaminated, dangerous, I don't think forgetting about Ginny's experiences is necessarily much of a sin, nor is not talking to her about it, I think it's at least partly that he put his foot in it by stating so baldly that he forgot - not the most tactful response

Comment: @Valorum Haha by all means I never assumed this answer would be complete, I'd be happy for you to post a competing answer. The pensieve one is a great example :) I think the one about the additional security (book 7) is pretty harsh to describe as really his fault. The polite thing to do is obviously to apologise for being an inconvenience and the natural response is to feel a bit guilty, but it's not his fault he's a marked man and he didn't rock up to the wedding uninvited and expect security :P

Comment: @Au101 - Nah. Sling 'em into yours and make it complete. You're already 75% of the way there.

Comment: @Valorum Well thanks very much =)

Comment: Hopefully the OP won't forget to attribute their research when writing their stuff :-)